# How should I interpret this regression coefficient

Tags: regression, inference, data-transformation

So I have the model:

$$\ln(V_{it})=\beta_1\Delta\ln(A_{it})$$
$$\ln(V_{it})=\beta_1[\ln(A_{it})-\ln(A_{it-1})]$$
$$\ln(V_{it})=\beta_1\bigg[\ln\bigg(\frac{A_{it}}{A_{it-1}}\bigg)\bigg]$$

I am having some trouble interpreting the effect of a change in the change in $A_{it}$, it seems somewhat unintuitive.

Would I be correct in saying that a percentage increase in the growth from $A_{it-1}$ to $A_{it}$ leads to a $\beta_1\%$ increase in $V_{it}$. I presume this wouldn't apply for extreme values - but in a general sense?